# Copy to clipboard with masked textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

New to C# so forgive me if i am missing something simple here.

I am trying to set a labelink(On click) to copy the text of a maskedtextbox(phone number) to the clipboard minus the mask. I have set the property in the maskedtextbox to include literals only. If i select the text and ctrl+c it works perfectly. I cannot get this to work on a button click though i have tried `Clipboard.SetText(custBtnText.Text);` and it will run but it gives me 000-000-0000 and i need 0000000000. Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @hans no need. It's much simpler than that. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the `masked.TextMaskFormat=MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals` and then call .Text

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used that control but, in this case, you could always try something like this:

```
Clipboard.SetText(custBtnText.Text.Replace("-", "");
```

But when working with user input, I'd be a little more thorough. For example, if I really only wanted digits, I might loop through each character and only save those that are digits. Depends on your requirements though.

```
string GetDigits(string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in s)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(c))
            sb.Append(c);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @ Jonathan `Clipboard.SetText(custBtnText.Text.Replace("-", ""));` worked perfectly. I think it should suffice as well because with the masked box they can only enter the text a specific way anyway so it will always have the "-". Thanks so much works great!